# How to delete all cloudwatch log groups and stream by date?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

After some time using AWS I find my cloudwatch is full of obsolete logs, is there a way to delete all log groups and streams by date? So I can clear all previous year logs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While you can set the retention period on a stream as @DominikHelps said, that just deletes the messages; it will not delete the stream itself.

You can use the CLI to find the streams for a log group, along with the time they're created:

```
aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name Example --output text --query 'logStreams[*].[creationTime,logStreamName]' | sort -rn
```

This gives you output that looks like this:

```
1544374120302   stream1
1544373223032   stream2
1544365017774   stream3
```

The numbers are epoch timestamps, in milliseconds. You can use a tool like [this](https://www.epochconverter.com/) to translate them into human-readable timestamps. Then, once you've identified the stream(s) that you want to delete, you can again use the CLI:

```
aws logs delete-log-stream --log-group-name Example --log-stream-name stream1
```

It's a fairly easy step from doing this manually to doing it as a cronjob. And if you don't mind programming, turning it into a Lambda that's invoked by a CloudWatch Events scheduled event.

Comment: for a "solution" to log streams proliferation look into https://github.com/gene1wood/delete-empty-cloudwatch-logstreams

Answer (score 4):

Logs are kept indefinitely by default.

How ever you can set this by log group:

**Log Retention—By default, logs are kept indefinitely and never expire. You can adjust the retention policy for each log group, keeping the indefinite retention, or choosing a retention periods between 10 years and one day.**

More Info here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html

How to change log data retention:
[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Working-with-log-groups-and-streams.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Working-with-log-groups-and-streams.html#:%7E:text=Change%20log%20data%20retention%20in%20CloudWatch%20Logs)

Comment: does it deletes the stream or the data inside it.

Comment: @Unbreakable I think it only deletes the events. I have set retention of all log groups to expire after 1 day but I see streams that are older than a month but the events inside them are empty.

Comment: @August thanks so much for this!! Would've spent so much time trying to figure it out instead of just clicking into one of the streams to see no data

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, because it being evicted by retention leaves all the stream names there in the list, it just truncates everything inside them, so when you view them, it looks like it has no rows and it shows a blundering "waiting for events" `Load More` interface. This answer says what I would say if someone asked. The real answer is, the implementation of retention in cloudwatch is designed to make you waste space.